# Won't Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) generate uneven probabilities?

Tags: javascript, math, random, probability

Was thinking through the logic and it seemed that `Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)` would generate uneven probabilities of each value being generated.

For example, a number of values can round down to 254, but only when `Math.random()` generates exactly 1 will the output be 255. How uneven the probabilities are depends on how many decimal digits `Math.random()` generates to.

Am I incorrect in my thinking here or is there a more balanced way to generate a set of random integers?

Comment: Um, Math.random [never returns 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Math.random()` will always generate a number that is strictly less than 1 (i.e, `0 ≤ x < 1`), so `Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)` will generate a random number between 0 and 254.

Use `Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)` to generate a number between 0 and 255. Yes, the results will be evenly distributed.

Comment: +1; [here's the spec reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.14): "*...greater than or equal to 0 but less than 1...*"

Comment: Got it, thanks. The tutorial I was going through said to use * 255, but I see why 256 makes more sense (and why the spec is equal to 0 but less than 1).

Comment: What tutorial are you using? You may want to look for a better one. :)

Answer (score 2):

This will generate a random integer for you below 256:

```
Math.random()*256|0;
```

Note that, it wont work for huge numbers, though. And, yes, it will generate evenly distributed numbers :)